# Django: .is_superuser field not working

Tags: python, django

I am trying to set the boolean field of `is_superuser` of the generic `User` Django model to `True` via the following code...

```
User.objects.create(username = 'Randy', email = 'randy@gmail.com', password = 'admin', is_superuser = True)
```

Does the `is_superuser` field require anything else? Or am I doing something obviously wrong?

Things I have tried...

1) `is_superuser = 'True'`

2) `is_superuser = 'true'`

3) `is_superuser = true`

4) `is_superuser = True`

Comment: What's going wrong? The user doesn't save? Or the superuser status is not set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'True'` is a Python string, not a boolean. It has to be `True`. Your code worked perfectly for me. Let me copy paste from my Terminal:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.create(username = 'Randy', email = 'randy@gmail.com', password = 'admin', is_superuser = True)
>>> user
<User: Randy>
>>> user.is_superuser
True
>>>
```

However I see you used a plain text password. Please use `make_password` for such cases: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password

Comment: You're right. I tried it again and it worked just fine.. What in the world?

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def blah(args):
    User.objects.create_superuser(username='admin', password='123', email='')
```